# Syntax error missing semicolon in switch inside function

Tags: function, syntax, switch-statement, processing

```
void placeSlagschip(){

    switch(organizationBoats){
        case 1:
            positionSlagschip = {
                {BOARD[0, 0], BOARD[1, 0]},
                {BOARD[0, 1], BOARD[1, 0]},
                {BOARD[0, 2], BOARD[1, 0]},
                {BOARD[0, 3], BOARD[1, 0]}
            };
            break;
        case 2:
            positionSlagschip = {
                {BOARD[0, 8], BOARD[1, 1]},
                {BOARD[0, 8], BOARD[1, 2]},
                {BOARD[0, 8], BOARD[1, 3]},
                {BOARD[0, 8], BOARD[1, 4]},
            };
            break;
        case 3:
            positionSlagschip = {
                {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 9]},
                {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 8]},
                {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 7]},
                {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 6]},
            };
            break;
    }
}
```

Gives error on the first line after the case 1; "positionSlagschip = {":

`Syntax Error - Missing operator, semicolon, or ‘}’ near ‘{’?`

I have checked the reference of Processing and the switch is properly written, the function as well, i just dont know what is  the problem. If someone could help me, appreciate it.

Comment: Could you add enough code for it to become runnable, so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Explain how did You init `BOARD`?

Comment: Sidenote: your first block does not have a comma after the fourth BOARD line. The other two do. That won't affect compilation, but it's the kind of inconsistency that shouldn't be in your code.

Comment: I edited the posts with the new problem after the answer of @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans . I also added what you guys asked me for. I hope that there is now enough info.

Comment: Solved. Check last answer for a resume of what the problems were.

Comment: Don't change your question once you get an answer. If you have _new_ problems, that's a _new_ post. Your original question was about the use of array assignment using `{...}`, and so people wrote answers for that. If _that_ got addressed, you pick the answer that best helped resolve it, and accept it. You do _not_ change the post to a completely different question: SO is not "for you", it's "for all of us" and your question getting an answer means future visitors with the _same_ question can find the (question + answer) pair on this website.

Comment: (also, the fact that you solve the "new" problem on you own means there was no problem. You fixed the problem you asked about with the help of people here, and then you fixed the rest yourself, so _there was no problem there_. If you get an error but you know how to fix it yourself, there is no programming problem, only programming)

Answer (score 2):

The `{...}` notation for creating an array only works as part of a "declare and initialize" instruction, e.g.

```java
int[][] positionSlagschip = {
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 9]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 8]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 7]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 6]},
}
```

If you want to assign an array *after* some earlier declaration of the variable you're assigning the array to, you need to explicitly create a new array of the correct type:

```java
int[][] positionSlagschip;

// ...

positionSlagschip = new int[][]{
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 9]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 8]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 7]},
  {BOARD[0, 5], BOARD[1, 6]},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

void placeSlagschip(){

```
switch(organizationBoats){
    case 1:
        positionSlagschip = new int[][]{
            {BOARD[0][0], BOARD[1][0]},
            {BOARD[0][1], BOARD[1][0]},
            {BOARD[0][2], BOARD[1][0]},
            {BOARD[0][3], BOARD[1][0]}
        };
        break;
```

And like that with all the cases... Basically, my two mistakes were:

1- the declaration-initialization mistake that @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans explained above.

2- I was writing wrong the reference to the data stored in the array BOARD. I mean:

WRONG: {BOARD[0,0],BOARD[1,0], blabla...

CORRECT: {BOARD[0][0], BOARD[1][0], blabla...

So, basically, both of them truly stupid beginner mistakes. D:

Thanks to all of the people that tried to help me here :D